# quantile regression graph (grqreg) interprets titles with multiple words as associated with multiple graphs

Tags: stata

I use qreg in Stata to run a quantile regression, then I want to graph a quantile regression plot for one coefficient using grqreg. I can produce a graph without any issues as long as I don't try to title it.
When I put my title in "*variable - dataset*" I get the error message:

> Number of titles different from number of variables

Some example code outlining the problem is below:

```
*setup
webuse auto, clear
keep price mpg headroom foreign
compress
*running quantile regression
qreg price mpg headroom foreign
*creating a quantile regression plot for the binary variable foreign
grqreg foreign, ci ols olsci graphregion(color(white))

*so far everything works and is uncontroversial
*now i quietly re-run the quantile regression 
quietly: qreg price mpg headroom foreign
*and try to put a title on this graph with multiple words
*none of the below work
*grqreg always seems to think that each word in the title relates to a variable
grqreg foreign, ci ols olsci title(this is a title using multiple words)
grqreg foreign, ci ols olsci title("this is a title using multiple words")
grqreg foreign, ci ols olsci title('this is a title using multiple words')
grqreg foreign, ci ols olsci title((this is a title using multiple words))

*one worded title 
quietly: qreg price mpg headroom foreign
grqreg foreign, ci ols olsci title(this_is_a_title_with_one_word)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I've edited the title. It's clear that the `title()` option of `grqreg` works as its author intended and documented. So, the problem is not that the program misinterprets a command; it is that you want something different from that behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grqreg` is a user-written command from SSC and must be installed before your code can be attempted. On [Statalist](http://www.statalist.org/forums/help#stata) you'd be expected to explain that and there's no reason for lower standards here.

You're correct that the `title()` option is programmed to peel off one word for each graph used, but although that is idiosyncratic, the option is documented in the help for `grqreg` as working in that way. Trying to force a multiple word title even with `" "` to bind won't work as the option is declared `title(string)` which means that the string delimiters are stripped on input. You could try to subvert that by hacking at the code to insist on `title(string asis)`. However, that doesn't seem worth the bother as there is a much easier work-around.

The option `t1title()` is available to you. If getting the style and/or position the same as `title()` would do normally is important to you, then add suboptions as needed.

```
* setup
webuse auto, clear
keep price mpg headroom foreign
compress

* running quantile regression
qreg price mpg headroom foreign

* creating a quantile regression plot for the binary variable foreign
* must install previously with -ssc inst grqreg- 
grqreg foreign, ci ols olsci graphregion(color(white))

* so far everything works and is uncontroversial
* now I quietly re-run the quantile regression 
quietly: qreg price mpg headroom foreign
*and try to put a title on this graph with multiple words

* t1title() is a work-around for title()
* grqreg foreign, ci ols olsci t1title(this is a title using multiple words)
grqreg foreign, ci ols olsci t1title(this is a title using multiple words, size(large) )
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, that works like a charm. You are right, I forgot to point out that grqreg is a user-written command that needs to be installed separately, apologies.